# Restore deleted People contacts

Tags: contacts

My daughter went through my phone and deleted any contact she didn't know!  My Outlook account has now synchronised and the Contacts are lost everywhere.  Spent half hour talking to Microsoft but got nowhere.  the Contacts aren't in the Deleted folder on my laptop either.  Can I get my deleted contacts back please?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the deleted contacts were in your Outlook.com account (not, say, Exchange or Office 365). If so, try the following:

1. Go to https://outlook.live.com and log in
2. In the lower left corner, click the People icon [image]
3. In the sidebar, select the "Deleted" folder

If any contacts show up there, you can restore them. Otherwise, I am afraid you are out of luck.

Source: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/435db2fb-555e-493b-8bd0-ae9c39a2a622